# Proving that G is a group if a∗x=b and y∗a=b have solutions: detailed explanation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is the following problem:

> Prove that a set $ G \neq \emptyset$, together with an associative binary operation $ * $ on $ G $ such that $ a * x = b $ and $ y * a = b $ have solutions in $ G $  for any $ a,b \in G $, is a group.

I looked at existing proofs and they all start with:

> $ ax = a $ has a solution $ e $

My question: 
How does one know this? In my eyes those proofs come up with unproven "facts" (or a hypotheses?) that serve as a base for the rest of the proof.

In this case assuming that ax = a even has a solution feels like skipping a part of the proof that may be intuitive for some, but I would like to have no such skips.

How can this be explained in more detail? Giving out the full proof with detailed explanations would be really appreciated!

Comment: By assumption $ax=b$ has a solution for $a,b\in G$. Now what does this say for $a=b$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde If $ e := e : ae = b \Rightarrow a = b $, otherways $ a \neq b $. It depends on $ x $ really, but can we assume that a right hand identity does or does not exist just like this?

Comment: It says that $ax=a$ has a solution, by assumption. This is a right unit in $G$. We may call it $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the hypothesis of $ax=b$ having solution for every $a,b\in G$. Since $G\neq\emptyset$ you can take $a\in G$ ($a=b$ in this case) and write $ax=a$, which by hypothesis has solution that they call $e$.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions read in a more formalized manner
$$\tag1\forall a\in G\colon\forall b\in G\colon\exists x\in G\colon a*x=b $$
and
$$\tag2\forall a\in G\colon\forall b\in G\colon\exists y\in G\colon y*a=b. $$
As $G\ne 0$, we can pick an element $c\in G$. Then by specialization from 
$(1)$, 
$$\forall b\in G\colon\exists x\in G\colon c*x=b $$
and by another specialization,
$$\tag3\exists x\in G\colon c*x=c.$$
We pick one such element of $G$ and give it a name, $e$. So 
$$ c*e=c.$$
Note that as of now, $e$ may not be unqiquely determiend and may depend on $c$ (and may differ from the similarly picked $e'$ with the property $e'*c=c$).